# R, to get to know missing values in a column

Tags: r

I am new to R and learning from the [titanic data](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.xls).

I want to know how many values are missing in a column. this is what I tried:

```
data = read.csv(file.path(DIR, file))

table(is.na(data$name))
table(is.na(data$cabin))
```

there's no missing values in the column Name.
there are 1,014 missing values in the column Cabin.

however above lines returned me:

```
FALSE
1309
```

what's the right way? thank you.

Comment: If you are checking `is.na` shouldn't you be checking the `TRUE` value instead to get `NA` values? What is your expected outcome?

Comment: @RonakShah  I think the OP showed the number of FALSE elements  i.e. non-NA for cabin column as 1309 which is the same as the number of rows.  For some reason, the `NA` was not being as read as real NAs.  The OP stated that `here are 1,014 missing values in the column Cabin.` which was not correctly read

Comment: I don't understand why this is put on hold.  The OP included the dataset and the code he used along with the expected output.  If the person didn't the question correctly and commented something, will it be put on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is `.xls` file.  We can read it with one of the packages that reads excel files

```
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel(file.choose())
dim(data)
#[1] 1309   14

table(is.na(data$cabin))

#  FALSE  TRUE 
#  295  1014
```

To get the missing values in all the columns, `summarise_all` would be useful

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
# A tibble: 1 x 14
#    pclass survived  name   sex   age sibsp parch ticket  fare cabin embarked  boat  body home.dest
#    <int>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>    <int> <int> <int>     <int>
#1      0        0     0     0   263     0     0      0     1  1014        2   823  1188       564
```

Comment: thank you for the teaching! :)